# Laravel Displays a blank screen after deploying to goddady servers

Tags: php, laravel, server

Am new to Laravel, actually I've not been able to upload any laravel project on a remote server and it worked.
I've been working on my localhost for my projects for quit sometime, on install on laravel rom local host, I had the same problem but just had to change the permissions of the storage folder. but on the remote server, i tried changing the permissions but every thing failed.

Comment: check `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` folder write permission

Comment: Check the server logs? Is it only a blank screen? Is your DocumentRoot pointing to `/public`?

Comment: Check the directory permissions. Mostly the storage directory permissions and bootstrap folder permission.

Answer (score 0):

please try the following.

```
1.Open-> bootstrap (folder) ->app.php (file)
   change existing realpath to  realpath(__DIR__.'/../')

2. take all the contents of "public" folder to the project root folder

3. open index.php in project root folder -> change existing code to "require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';"

4. change existing code to $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

This has got nothing to do with file permissions or anything.

I hope this may solve your issue.

Comment: If it worked, then please mark the answer as correct. Thank You.